# Url not giving & for &amp;

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When I am fetching url from web.config :-

```
<add key="URL" value="https://abc.co/v2/Source=1000&amp;Function=something" />
```

When I am fetching this url from web.config :-

```
URL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"];
```

It is giving me correctcly `&` instead of `&amp;` within URL and URL is getting processed.

But when I do it through json and read it in c# , I get url with `&amp;`

How can I get url with `&` instead of `&amp;` in case of when I am reading it from json as I get through web.config ?

Comment: It hurt my brain to read this.  Have you looked at maybe leveraging System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode or System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode or similar?

Comment: `& instead of &` I'm not sure I understand? You might want to show the value you get and what exactly is wrong with it

Comment: `&amp;` is an *XML* entity. When you read from XML using XML tools, XML entities are decoded. `&amp;` has no special meaning in JSON - why would you expect a JSON tool to perform XML entity decoding?

Comment: @EpicKip - I've edited to make it clear (hopefully) where in the question they were using literal `&`s and where they were including `&amp;` HTML entities. They obviously didn't pay attention to the preview.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah now I actually understand the question, thanks :)